# Add relevant tag to search results

Tags: php, search, tags

Tags are a major part of my platform. Using the default search, **if** the search term matches a tag, on the results page, I want it to display:

```
<p>Are you looking for our <a href="TAG-URL">TAG-Name</a> page?</p>
```

The tag must have at least one post attached to it, so no empty tags. What would be the *lightest* solution to achieve this? Our search feature is used very frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In functions.php:

```
function wpse82525_link_search_to_tag()
{
    // check if search archive is being displayed
    if( ! is_search() )
        return;

    // get search query var
    $sqv = get_query_var( 's' );

    // get tag base
    $tagbase = get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) 
        ? get_option( 'tag_base' ) 
            ? trailingslashit( get_option( 'tag_base' ) )
            : 'tag/' 
        : '?tag=';

    // return link if matching tag is found
    return ( get_term_by( 'slug', $sqv, 'post_tag' ) )
        ? '<p>' . sprintf( 
            __( 'Are you looking for our <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a> page?', 'txtdomain' ),
            home_url( $tagbase . sanitize_title_with_dashes( $sqv ) ),
            $sqv
        ) . '</p>'
        : '';
}
```

In search.php:

```
<?php echo wpse82525_link_search_to_tag(); ?>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, only one problem. I want to exclude tags that have no posts attached to them. Is this possible? Because currently it lists tags that are empty as well.

Comment: Sure! Just replace `return ( get_term_by( 'slug', $sqv, 'post_tag' ) )` with `$obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $sqv, 'post_tag' ); return ( $obj && $obj->count >= 1 )`

Comment: It is clear that you seem to be in full control of your coding skills - works perfectly, Answer accepted.